# How do I block SSH access on Mac OSX?

Tags: macbook-air

Hackers have gained root access my Mac OS X using SSH remote access and automatic WiFi login. How do I block login access to SSH?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output, of the following command, `sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin`

Comment: The root bug was only publicly known for 24h before Apple released a patch. If you haven't yet updated... now would be the time. Otherwise, there is no route to root on a Mac; it is disabled by default so you would have had to manually open that door.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I block login access to SSH?

You should run the following command from the command line.

> `sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin off`

It might be worth pointing out, that the command will prompt you, to confirm you actually want this feature off.

> When you successfully execute the command, you will be asked: “Do you
>   really want to turn remote login off? If you do, you will lose this
>   connection and can only turn it back on locally at the server
>   (yes/no)?” so type “yes” to confirm, which will disable SSH and also
>   disconnect any active SSH connections to the Mac in question.

You can avoid that prompt by using the following command.

> `sudo systemsetup -f -setremotelogin off`

### Sources

- [Turn Off SSH on Mac OS with systemsetup](http://osxdaily.com/2016/08/16/enable-ssh-mac-command-line/)